# Enforcing that a given RegExp is case insensitive

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript function that receives a regular expression as one of its arguments. I would like to make sure that the RegExp has the i (case insensitive) modifier, and if not, add it.

```
var caseInsensitiveMatch = function (rx) {
  // TODO: verify that rx has the i modifier. Add it if it doesn't
  return rx.exec('mY tExT');
}

// both should match:
caseInsensitiveMatch(/my text/);
caseInsensitiveMatch(/my text/i);
```

What's an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to preserve all flags and just add case-insensitivity:

```
function caseInsensitiveMatch(rx, text) {
  var flags = 'i';
  if (rx.multiline) flags += 'm';
  if (rx.global) flags += 'g';
  return (new RegExp(rx.source, flags)).test(text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't familiar with the source property of RegExp.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regex.source` property and construct a new `RegExp` by adding `i` flag to make it ignore case:

```
var caseInsensitiveMatch = function (rx) {
   var flags = rx.toString().replace(/.*\//, "").replace("i", "") + "i";
   return (new RegExp(rx.source, flags)).test('mY tExT');
}

caseInsensitiveMatch(/my text/);
//=> true
caseInsensitiveMatch(/my text/i);
//=> true
caseInsensitiveMatch(/MY TEXT/mig);
//=> true
caseInsensitiveMatch(new RegExp("MY TEXT", "mgi"));
//=> true
caseInsensitiveMatch(new RegExp("MY TEXT", "mg"));
//=> true
```

Comment: Note that this would remove any _other_ flags, if you care about that.